# Dozer (Java) like port for PHP?

Tags: php, dozer

I am looking for a [Dozer](http://dozer.sourceforge.net/) clone for PHP.

Dozer for Java is an object to object mapping framework.

Is there any PHP library to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well PHP is way more dynamic than Java, so it is not really hard to implement your own little framework, as a simple example e.g. something like this:

```
$mymapping = array(
    "prop1" => "otherName1",
    "prop2" => "otherName2");

$obj1 = new Object1();
$obj2 = new Object2();

function mapObjects($mapping, $object1, $object2)
{
    foreach($mapping as $obj1Property => $obj2Property)
    {
        $object2->$obj2Property = $object1->$obj1Property;
    }
}

mapObjects($mymapping, $obj1, $obj2);
```

Answer (score 1):

I did a small port a few years back:
https://github.com/activeingredient/AiToolBundle/blob/master/Service/Dozer.php

A more complete data mapper (as a Symfony bundle) can be found here:
https://github.com/michelsalib/BCCAutoMapperBundle

Answer (score 1):

I have found AutoMapper+ (https://github.com/mark-gerarts/automapper-plus) recently and totally satisfied with it. Highly flexible and easy to use DTO mapper.